# How to get POST multipart/form-data data before sending the request with libcurl in C++?

Tags: c++, curl, post, multipartform-data, libcurl

I'm making a POST multipart/form-data request using libcurl in C++. Before making the request, I need to calculate a cryptographic hash from the multipart/form-data encoded POST data.

My problem is I don't know how to get this data, and it is even more difficult because I have to get it before actually making the request.

Is it possible to get the POST data that libcurl encodes when you ask it to use multipart/form-data encoding? If not, is it possible to manually do the multipart/form-data encoding and ask libcurl to use it?